# How to regain health/hit points in Dungeon Siege III?

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

I'm playing the demo of Dungeon Siege III and noticed that my hit points are not automatically regenerating. But I also did not notice any health potions to drink or something like that. Sometimes enemies drop these green, glowing orbs that give back some health, but I haven't found other ways of regaining my hit points.

What ways are there in Dungeon Siege III to replenish my hit points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hit points are regained from :

- Green orbs
- Defensive skills (activated with spheres)
- Skill bonuses that gives hit point from hits on enemies
- Vampiric weapons (??)
- Saving game

Answer (score 8):

Each character has a health ability that they can use if they have enough will (mana).  Other than that, the orbs that enemies drop are the only way to restore health/will.  There are no potions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also regain health by saving the game.

Comment: By saving, or by saving and then loading the same save?

Comment: Saving seems to be not enabled in the demo, at least I never found an option for it.

Comment: @Fabian Yup! There's a savepoint right at the start of the second stage, and all it does is show a message about this being only a demo.

Comment: @Kissaki: When you save, it fully restores your health and focus.

Comment: @Ulla  Not quite.  Focus is not restored.  And you don't actually have to save, just using the save point to open the saving screen is enough to restore your health.

Comment: @bwarner: Yep, realized that right after posting. ;)